# Loss of decimal places when calculating mean in R

Tags: r

I have a list entitled SET1Bearing1slope with nine numbers, and each number has at least 10 decimal places. When I use the mean() function on the list I get an arithmetic mean

[image: Calculated arithmetic mean].

Yet if I list the numbers individually and then use the mean() function, I get a different output

[image: Different calculated arithmetic mean]

I know that this is caused by a rounding and that the second mean is more accurate. Is there a way to avoid this issue? What method can I use to avoid rounding errors when calculating the mean?

Comment: That's because that's not how you should be passing data to `mean`.  Notice that your mean in the second example is exactly the same as your first value.  Take a look at `?mean`

Comment: Also it's bad form to post your output as images.  Just copy and paste it directly.

Comment: If one of the answers below solves your problem, you should consider clicking the checkmark to accept the answer (mark the question as satisfactorily resolved, and reward the answerer)

Comment: Oh awesome! Thanks for helping me figure out how to navigate this website.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In R, `mean()` expects a vector of values, not multiple values. It is also a generic function so it is tolerant of additional parameters it doesn't understand (but doesn't warn you about them). See

```
mean(c(1,5,6))
# [1] 4
mean(1, 5, 6) #only "1" is used here, 5 and 6 are ignored.
# [1] 1
```

So in your example there are no rounding errors, you are just calling the function incorrectly.

Comment: Hey thanks again for the help! Such a silly error, but I would not have been able to remedy it without your help.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the difference in the way you're calling the function:

```
mean(c(1,2,5))
[1] 2.666667

mean(1,2,5)
[1] 1
```

As pointed by [MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick), in the first case you're passing a vector of numbers (the correct way); in the second, you're passing a list of arguments, and just the first one is considered.

As for the number of digits, you can specify it using `options()`:

```
options(digits = 10)

x <- runif(10)

x
[1] 0.49957540398 0.71266139182 0.07266473584 0.90541790240 0.41799820261
[6] 0.59809536533 0.88133668737 0.17078919476 0.92475634208 0.48827998806

mean(x)
[1] 0.5671575214
```

But remember that a greater number of digits is not necessarily better. There's a reason why R and others limits the number os digits. Check this topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significance_arithmetic

Comment: the hint to `options()` is very useful, as there is no hint in `?mean` on this dependency

Comment: Yes, but R can also give inappropiate few decimals. Normaly the Standard Error tells what is appropiate